# Filter with Q inside a span relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-q

I try to get tasks in context to the project they are belonging to. With an easy Project.objects.all() i get pretty much what i want. How can i filter this queryset in the best way?

**Models:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectname_text = models.CharField('Projectname', unique=True, max_length=200)

class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                related_name='tasks')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='author')
    editor = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='editor')
```

I tried with Q, but the result looks like it contains too many items and even items where the request.user is wrong. MAybe using Q is the wrong approach here?

Query in Views:

```
project_list = Project.objects.filter(Q(tasks__author=request.user) | 
                                      Q(tasks__editor=request.user))
```

**Template:**

```
{% for project in project_list %}
  html
  {% for task in project.tasks.all %}
    html
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your query criteria is wrong. `author` and `editor` are on model `Task` not on `Project`, so you should do:

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(Q(tasks__author=request.user) |
                                  Q(tasks__editor=request.user))
```

Secondly, never use `list` as your variable name, as that would override the default python data structure `list`, so you can no longer use `list()` to create a list after your variable declaration.

Comment: i actually used "project_list = Project.objects.filter(Q(tasks__author=request.user) | Q(tasks__editor=request.user))" because of the related_name='tasks' in the Task model. i just copied a wrong version -.-, Thanks for the list hint. The result is still weird, i get the wrong amount of projects with the wrong amount of task with authors that are not the request.user. :x

Comment: What do you really want to have? Your current way does this: get all projects that either has the author of the task as `request.user` or get editor of the task as `request.user`. If you only want tasks with author as request.user but not editor, why adding the second `Q` query?

Comment: when i use "project_list = Project.objects.all()" i can iterate in my template over all Projects and add all tasks that belong to Project below it. Now i want to filter that view to show just the tasks where the logged in user is the editor or author.

Comment: Then my suggestion does exactly just that. You said earlier `i get the wrong amount of projects with the wrong amount of task with authors that are not the request.user` sounds like you only check if author is `request.user`?

Comment: Maybe you get duplicates, you could do `projects = projects.distinct()` to de-duplicate.

Comment: Nice, looks better now, but i still have entrys where neither the editor nor the author is the logged in user.

Comment: Sorry I don't know, I couldn't imagine how that wouldn't work. How do you verify the result?

Comment: I just look at the rendered html. And some entrys (it´s an <ul>) have users that are not the user thats logged in :/

Comment: You need to verify it in your views, maybe your template code is not working. Do a for loop and check `if project.author != request.user and project.editor != request.user` then print something.

Comment: I couldn´t find my error. instead i solved it with prefetch_related             project_list = Project.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('task_set',queryset=Task.objects.filter(Q(author=request.user) | Q(editor=request.user)))).all()